# Deploying custom MBeans to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, jmx, mbeans

I'm starting development of a Hadoop application and I'd like to manage it via a couple of `MBeans`.  I've experimented with using `MBeanUtils.register` and `MBeanServer`'s `register` method in jar files I'm running via `bin/hadoop.sh` jar.

The registration code isn't reporting an error, but I can't see the new `MBeans` via the JMX RESTful API.  How do I make the `MBeans` visible?